# How to synchronize local music in android music player

Tags: android, android-music-player

The Android native music player will always display scanning the SD card when it is opened, and it cannot be displayed in time after importing music. How to realize that after importing local music, restart the App to automatically display the newly added music。
Thanks for answering！

Comment: Are you notifying adapter? if yes then please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054774/how-load-songs-from-special-folder-on-sd-card-in-my-listview-and-play-it

Comment: I don't know which file of package/apps/music source code should be modified and how to modify it.